# DocuSign API - Send Template Returns Error 'IN_PERSON_SIGNER_NAME_CANNOT_BE_BLANK'

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to send an envelope using a DocuSign Template which uses In Person Signers but I keep getting this error:

```
{
"errorCode": "IN_PERSON_SIGNER_NAME_CANNOT_BE_BLANK",
"message": "For In Person Signer type, the Recipient Signer Name cannot be blank."
}
```

I'm just wanting to use the Template tabs that are setup in the Template so my request is very simple - I'm just specifying the Template Role as follows:

```
    {
    "disableResponsiveDocument" : false,
    "emailBlurb" : "",
    "emailSubject" : "Please DocuSign Company Agreement",
    "recipients" : 
    {
        "carbonCopies" : []
    },
    "status" : "sent",
    "templateId" : "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx",
    "templateRoles" : 
    [
        {
            "email" : "john@acmetrading.com",
            "name" : "John Simpson",
            "roleName" : "Customer",
            "routingOrder" : "1",
            "tabs" : {}
        }
    ]
}
```

I've used this format in the past successfully for regular signers but can't work out how to get around this error for In Person Signers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For In Person Signer you have 2 people invovled - the signer and the host. The host is the person that gets the email and then will ask the singer to sign (different person). You don't have to specify the signer email, but you could add `signerEmail` property if you want. You do have to specify the host name and email. See below:

```
{
    "disableResponsiveDocument" : false,
    "emailBlurb" : "",
    "emailSubject" : "Please DocuSign Company Agreement",
    "recipients" : 
    {
        "carbonCopies" : []
    },
    "status" : "sent",
    "templateId" : "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx",
    "templateRoles" : 
    [
        {
            "singerName" : "John Simpson",
            "hostEmail" :  "host@acmetrading.com"
            "hostName" : "Host Simpson"
            "roleName" : "Customer",
            "routingOrder" : "1",
            "tabs" : {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've tried making those changes - I changed `singerName` to `signerName` but I'm still getting the same  error. Anything else that could be causing this?

Comment: Is the correct property name here `inPersonSignerName` instead of `signerName`? That seems to progress further with my API request.

Comment: it's signerName, but you have to add hostName and hostEmail too